# Filter a Subform with a ComboBox - ACCESS 2013

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2013

How do I filter a Subform with a ComboBox. I have a ComboBox called FETextbox, it is populated with names from [tblMatterList]![Lead_FE]. I also have a subform called SubFormPF which when I select a name from FETextbox I want to filter to only show the rows with that name.

Here's what I have so far, this worked with a TextBox but doesn't with a combo box.

```
Private Sub FETextbox_Change()
Me.Filter = (Me.FETextbox = qryPlannedHours.Lead_FE)
Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated!
If I've missed anything to help you let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The filter property needs to be set to a string that is the where part of a select statement (without the word "where").

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194672.aspx